# Select and input form boxes won't line up using flex

Tags: html, css, forms, sass, flexbox

On my form I have title, first name and last name on the top line. I am using flex to give the title 20% width and the first and last name 80% between them. Firstly, the title box isn't ever fully in line with the first and last names boxes, it is very minimally taller. Secondly, when my validation error messages show the title box completely moves out of place.

I have tried to research the different styling rules of select boxes but can't seem to find anything that would help. I could wrap all three boxes in one container but then I would have to give them all equal widths?

This is what happens when I submit the select box moves out of place:

[image]

```css
h2 {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1d71b8 0%, #34a2c3 100%);
     color: white;
     padding: 1rem;
     width: calc(100% + 3rem);
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 1.3rem;
     text-align: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 form {
     background-color: white;
     box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgb(0 0 0 /15%);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 75%;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     border-radius: 10px;
}
 .information {
     padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .form-title {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     width: 100%;
}
 .form-title label {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     color: #454545;
     width: calc(50% - 1rem);
}
 .form-title span {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-top: 0.5rem;
     font-size: 1rem;
}
 .form-title input {
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     margin: 0.2em 0 0;
     padding: 0.7em 1em;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
 .name {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 100%;
}
 .titles {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 20%;
}
 .titles select {
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     appearance: none;
     padding: 0;
}
 .titles label {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     display: flex;
     align-items: end;
}
 .titles input {
     width: 100%;
}
 .first-last {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 80%;
}
 .first-last label {
     width: calc(50% - 1rem);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/Submit.php" id="mailingListForm">
  <div class="form-title">
    <h2>Form</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="information">
    <div class="name">
      <div class="titles">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <select id="title" name="title">
          <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
          <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
          <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
          <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div class="first-last">
        <label for="firstname">
            <span>First Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstname">
            <span>First name is required</span>
        </label>
        
        <label for="lastname">
            <span>Last Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastname">
            <span>Last name is required</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Suraj Sanwal has edited it to show CSS

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't seem to show the problem. Please make do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the following snippet. You need to style `.titles` class with the given below properties:

```
.titles {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 width: 20%;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Hopefully, This solves your problem.

```css
h2 {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1d71b8 0%, #34a2c3 100%);
     color: white;
     padding: 1rem;
     width: calc(100% + 3rem);
     margin: 0;
     font-size: 1.3rem;
     text-align: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 form {
     background-color: white;
     box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgb(0 0 0 /15%);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 75%;
     overflow: hidden;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: flex-start;
     border-radius: 10px;
}
 .information {
     padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .form-title {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     width: 100%;
}
 .form-title label {
     margin-top: 1rem;
     color: #454545;
     width: calc(50% - 1rem);
}
 .form-title span {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-top: 0.5rem;
     font-size: 1rem;
}
 .form-title input {
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     margin: 0.2em 0 0;
     padding: 0.7em 1em;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
 .name {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 100%;
}
 .titles {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     width: 20%;
     align-items: flex-start;
}
 .titles select {
     border: 1px solid #cccccc;
     appearance: none;
     padding: 0;
}
 .titles label {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     display: flex;
     align-items: end;
}
 .titles input {
     width: 100%;
}
 .first-last {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-between;
     width: 80%;
}
 .first-last label {
     width: calc(50% - 1rem);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/Submit.php" id="mailingListForm">
  <div class="form-title">
    <h2>Form</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="information">
    <div class="name">
      <div class="titles">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <select id="title" name="title">
          <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
          <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
          <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
          <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
          <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="first-last">
        <label for="firstname">
                                    <span>First Name</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstname">
            <span>First name is required</span>
                                </label>
        <label for="lastname">
                                    <span>Last Name</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastname">
     <span>Last name is required</span>
                                </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I will try now and test it, thank you

Comment: Glad if it helps. @BethanyJane

Answer (score 0):

You try adding some margin-bottom to it so it moves up on its own.